# Datatables sort images on title tag

Tags: datatables

I have a question about using a custom sorting option for datatables.
I have a table with only images in the last column. The images use the title tag, where I want to sort them on.

So, I use this code to set the sorting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
                "title-string-pre": function ( a ) {
                    return a.match(/title="(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
                },

                "title-string-asc": function ( a, b ) {
                    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
                },

                "title-string-desc": function ( a, b ) {
                    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
                }
            } );

            $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#customertable').dataTable( {
                             "aoColumnDefs": [ 
                             { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0,1 ] },
                             { "sType": "title-string-asc",   "aTargets": [ 4 ] }
                           ],

                            "bPaginate": false,
                            "bLengthChange": false,
                            "bFilter": false,
                            "bInfo": false,
                            "bAutoWidth": false,
                            "bSortCellsTop": true

                        } );
                    } );
</script>
```

However, when I click on the header of column 4, it does not work and Chrome reports errors "Property 'title-string-asc-desc' of object # is not a function" 
and 
"Property 'title-string-asc-asc' of object # is not a function"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, but don't understand it.

Changed
    { "sType": "title-string-asc",   "aTargets": [ 4 ] }
to
    { "sType": "title-string",   "aTargets": [ 4 ] }

Now it works. But why? "title-string" is defined nowhere. How can javascript link that string to the content of a title tag?

Comment: Title-string is its name, when you click the header it becomes title-string-asc or title-string-desc, which then uses your custom sort function...if your name was title-string-asc, it would become title-string-asc-asc and have the ref error